# Android's NfcA to python's pyscard (smartcard)

Tags: python, java, android, nfc, pyscard

I am backwards-engineering an android application (written in java) into a python application, where nfc (apdu) commands are sent. (ISO 14443-3A, if that helps)

The android applications makes use of the `android.nfc.tech.NfcA` library and sends commands such as:

```
import android.nfc.tech.NfcA;
NfcA nfca_tag;
byte[] message;
message = nfca_tag.transceive(new byte[]{48, 4});
// also with negative numbers:
message = nfca_tag.transceive(new byte[]{-51, 13};
```

On the python-side, using the pyscard module an example would look like this:

```
from smartcard.CardRequest import CardRequest

cardrequest = CardRequest( timeout=1, 
 cardType=cardtype )
cardservice = cardrequest.waitforcard()
cardservice.connection.connect()

data, sw1, sw2 = cardservice.connection.transmit([0xFF, 0xB0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F])
# respectively
data, sw1, sw2 = cardservice.connection.transmit([255, 176, 0, 0, 15])
```

What is the translation of the android NfcA's message (such as `{48, 4}`) to python pyscard's message (such as `[0xFF, 0xB0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F]')?

Now i know, that java bytes go from -128 to 127 and therefore whatever byte we have in java, we can translate it using this function

```
def java_byte_to_python(java_byte: int):
    return java_byte%256
```

However, it seems to me, that the NfcA module already has some bytes that are sent by default, as an apdu command requires at least 4 bytes?

---

Further information on the specific tag for this application:

- ISO/IEC 14443:3 (Type A) compatible

**Android technology information:**

1. TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.NfcA]
2. Maximum transceive length: 253 bytes
3. Default maximum transceive time-out: 618 ms

**Detailed protocol information**

- ID: 46:53:54:4E:31:31:6D
- ATQA: 0x4400
- SAK: 0x00
- ATS: 0xFFFF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is dependent on the smart card reader and tag that is used.

In my case, using an ACR1252U ([Product page](https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/342/acr1252u-usb-nfc-reader-iii-nfc-forum-certified-reader/)
& [API documentation](https://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/6402/API-ACR1252U-1.17.pdf)) and a Mifare Ultralight C:

1. Start a session:

```
cardservice.connection.transmit([0xFF, 0xC2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x81, 0x00])
```

2. Send command via transparent exchange "transceive" (0x95):

```
message_in_java_bytes = [48, 4]
message = [x%256 for x in message_in_java_bytes]
cardservice.connection.transmit([0xFF, 0xC2, 0x00, 0x01, len(message)+2, 0x95, len(message), *message])
```

(Card response format: C0 03 00 90 00 92 01 00 96 02 00 00 97 0C **[Card Response]** 90 00)

3. Close session

```
cardservice.connection.transmit([0xFF, 0xC2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x82, 0x00])
```

#### Some further documentation:

[Android Tag Operation commands](http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-2-Tag_1.1.pdf)

[Relation between APDU and ISO 14443-A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75203161/relation-between-apdu-and-higher-level-nfc-protocols-such-as-iso-14443-3a)

[NFC Forum Digital Protocol (this goes deep down the rabbit hole)](https://its-wiki.no/images/3/3b/NFC_forum_digital_protocol.pdf#page=44&zoom=100,117,308)